# Koszul complexes of twisting sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I am considering the following problem:

For the projective space $X=\mathbb P^n$ is there an exact sequence of the form

$0\rightarrow \binom{n+1}{n+1} \mathcal O(-n-1)\rightarrow \binom{n+1}{n}\mathcal O(-n)\rightarrow ... \rightarrow \binom{n+1}{1} \mathcal O(-1)\rightarrow \binom{n}{0}\mathcal O\rightarrow 0$

where for a sheaf $\mathcal F$ $m\mathcal F$ is shorthand for $\bigoplus_{i=1}^m \mathcal F$?

I tried proving it with Koszul complexes. For this I first tried to apply
[Koszul complex of locally free sheaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354451/koszul-complex-of-locally-free-sheaves)
but I couldn't find a locally free sheaf of rank $n+1$ which gives me my answer.

I also tried proving it locally, but the usual Koszul complex works with exterior products, I couldn't "switch them out" to direct sums.

Background: I am trying to prove that in the Grothendieck group of $\mathbb P^n$ for $H=[\mathcal O]-[\mathcal O(-1)]$

$H^{n+1}=0$, where the product in the Grothendieck group is defined by

$[E][F]=\sum \limits _{i=0}^n (-1)^i[Tor_i(E,F)]$

Could anyone point out a hint to proving the existence of such an exact sequence (if it exists)?

sincerely, slinshady

Comment: Yes, such an exact sequence exists and indeed is the Koszul complex starting with the right hand side map, which is obvious by choosing a basis for $H^0(\mathcal{O}(1))$.

Comment: locally I just have polynomial rings with shifted degree. But I only managed to show that this is a complex, how can I show that it is indeed exact?

Comment: Please read when a Koszul complex $K(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is exact. (Hint: when these form a regular sequence).